# How to switch user quickly, on Mojave?

Tags: applescript, shortcut, touch-id, fast-user-switching

There are two users enabled and used at the same time.
Usually I need to click via mouse the *username* in the top bar, choose the *username2*, type in the password.

Am wondering if there's a quicker way.

- Like a quick-action callable from the TouchBar; that would benefit also from the close fingerprint sensor over there.
- Or maybe simply using a shortcut, that I didn't find yet in the System Preferences.

Any ideas or insights[?](http://www.jackmorton.com/blog/the-insight-is-not-the-idea/)

Comment: To my knowledge that is the quickest way MacOS currently supports. Not sure if that can change with Catalina

Comment: Check my answer; on Mojave the user switch is just one (quick) click away! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Mojave it is simpler than I thought.

Clicking the power/fingerprint button will quickly bring the login screen out, with the other user already chosen, ready for the password to be inputed.

After the login it will be possible to switch with just `fingerprint-click` + `fingerprint` (for authentication).

That's pretty convenient!

**Note:** I am not sure if that was active also before, or if the alternative user is chosen based on what are the most active/logged users (because, in my case, the proposed user for login is not the only other user present on the system).

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard Maestro https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/ has a 'Fast User Switch' action. This can be linked to keyboard shortcuts - one for each user.  You will still need to enter the password for the user.

I suggest you would only buy Keyboard Maestro (US$36) if you intended to use it as an automation tool for other purposes as well as changing user.

Comment: That's a pretty expensive alternative; thank you for the suggestion though. In the end I've found out that the feature is natively supported by *macOS* (at least on Mojave). Have a look at my answer! :)

Comment: Much better solution.  It wouldn't work on an iMac, but solves your problem.  I will up vote your solution.